# Spring MVC/Jackson: how to ask Spring to validate the JSON object in the request body?

Tags: json, validation, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2.3 + Jackson 2.1.4 for JSON serialization.

I would like to known if it's possible to **ask Spring to validate the JSON object in the request body*, especially if a required field is missing** ?

I tries to set *@JsonProperty(require = true)* on one attribute of the Java bean but no exception seems to be raised when the field is missing in the JSON object of the request.

JSON in request body (missing "field1")

```
{
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
}
```

Controller code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myBaseUrl")
public class MyController{

    //...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/myUrl", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void handle(@RequestBody MyRequestBean requestBean) throws IOException {

        // code reach at execution whereas I expected the throw of an exception because "field1" is missing in JSON.
    }
}
```

Bean for the request:

```
public class MyRequestBean {
    //...

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String field1

    //...

    public String getField1(){ return field1; }
    public void setField1(String field1){ this.field1 = field1; }
}
```

Comment: Use [Spring's validation framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: Agree with Arun, validate your deserialized objects rather than the transport protocol.